# $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}=1^+$ and $\sum_k x_k$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x_k$, where $x_k>0$ for all $k\geq 0$. If $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}=1^+$, i.e. the ratio of consecutive terms converges to 1 from above, can the series converge? Intuitively I think this shouldn't be the case, but judging from the way the problem was given to me it should be possible. Despite this, in all the examples of the ratio test being inconclusive for a convergent series that I can think of, the ratio converges to 1 from below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it cannot converge. If you always have $\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}\geqslant1$, then you always have $x_{k+1}\geqslant x_k$. But, since each $x_k$ is greater than $0$, this is incompatible with having $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=0$.

Comment: Said another way, the $x_k$ are uniformly bounded from below by $\epsilon = \frac{x_0}{2}>0$.